# Link que puxa fonte do google esta causando deformação na pagina, no caso, colocando um &npsb do nada, como resolver?

Tags: html, css

link normais no head como mostrado na imagem abaixo,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já no navegador aparece um &npsb,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando tiro os links o &nbsp desaparece.

Comment: Experimenta tirando os dois links CSS reset.css e bios.css.

Comment: sam, fazendo isso toda estilisação da pagina vai embora, e mesmo fazendo isso o problema continua.

Answer (score -2):

**Consegui arrumar**, basicamente eu alterei os links,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**por**,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De alguma forma havia alguma informação errado nos links, mesmo trazendo as fontes normalmente, após alterar o problema sumiu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]